# $\epsilon$-$\delta$ Proof of Limit in $\mathbb{R}^4$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis, multivariable-calculus, epsilon-delta

**Question:** Determine $\lim_{(a,b,c,d) \to (0, 0, 0, 0)} \frac{a^2d^2 -2abcd + b^2c^2}{a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2}$ and prove your result using the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of a limit.

**Attempt:** I have completed the first part of the question using polar coordinates and found that the limit is $0$, but am having trouble proving my result.

Using $z=(a,b,c,d)$ and $f(z)=\frac{a^2d^2 -2abcd + b^2c^2}{a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2}$.

**RTP:** $\forall \epsilon>0, \exists \delta >0$ s.t. ($z \in \mathbb{R}^4$ and $0 < |z| < \delta$) $\Rightarrow$ $(|f(z)|< \epsilon)$

However, this is at a level (particularly being in $\mathbb{R}^4$) I am not at yet.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

> **Update:** I've realised I'm not sure what $0 < |z| < \delta$ is, since $|z| = |(a,b,c,d)|$. Do I evaluate $|(a,b,c,d)|$ using the Euclidean norm?

Comment: Does it help knowing that the numerator of $f(z)$ can be factorized? Namely,$$a^2d^2-2abcd+b^2c^2=(ad-bc)^2$$

Comment: @user170231 Would I use this for my $\delta$? I'm not sure of how much use this can be since the denominator cannot also be factorised to simplify $f(z)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limit is $0$. To see this, start by writing
$$\left| \frac{a^2d^2 -2abcd + b^2c^2}{a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2}-0\right|=\frac{|a^2d^2 -2abcd + b^2c^2|}{a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2}$$

$$\le \frac{a^2d^2}{a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2}+\frac{2|abcd|}{a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2}+\frac{b^2c^2}{a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2}$$

$$=a^2\frac{d^2}{a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2}+|cd|\frac{2|ab|}{a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2}+b^2\frac{c^2}{a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2}$$

$$\le a^2+ |cd|+b^2$$

Here, we have used the inequality $2|ab|\le a^2+b^2$ to bound the middle term. Then, note that the remaining fractions are all bounded above by $1$.

Applying $|cd|\le c^2+d^2$, we get that 
$$
\left| \frac{a^2d^2 -2abcd + b^2c^2}{a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2}-0\right|\le a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2
$$

So, given $\varepsilon>0$, taking $\delta=\sqrt{\varepsilon}$ does the trick.

In more detail, suppose $\varepsilon>0$ is given. Write $z=(a,b,c,d)$ and put $\delta:=\sqrt{\varepsilon}$. Obviously, $\delta>0$. Now, if $0<|z|<\delta$, then

$$ a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2=|z|^2<\delta^2=\varepsilon  $$

Combining this with the previous inequalities gives the desired result.

Comment: But if you have $|z|=|(a,b,c,d)|=\sqrt{a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2}$, then wont $0 < |z| < \delta$ turn out to be $0 < \sqrt{a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2} < \delta$ meaning that $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2 \not\le \epsilon$?

Comment: @RubyPa Oh, you're right, my apologies. Still, not all is lost, and you can take $\delta=\sqrt{\varepsilon}$. Then $|z|<\delta$ implies $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2<\varepsilon$.

Comment: Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 3):

you don't need an explicit coordinate system. Any
$$ \frac{(a,b,c,d)}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2}} $$
is a unit vector; let us use different names, maybe
$(p,q,r,s)$ such that $p^2 + q^2 + r^2 + s^2 = 1.$
Then your point
$$ (a,b,c,d) = t (p,q,r,s)  $$
so that $$ a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2 = t^2  $$
Next, $$(ad-bc)^2 = t^4 (pq-rs)^2$$
Now, how big can $|pq-rs|$ be? We know $-1 \leq p,q,r,s \leq 1$

Comment: Why does it matter that $\frac{(a,b,c,d)}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2}}$ is a unit vector? I haven't come across this when evaluating limits.

Comment: @RubyPa you mentioned polar coordinates. There are also spherical coordinates in dimension 3, there is a radius called $\rho$ and two trig variables. We could do the same thing in dimension 4, a radius coefficient then 3 trig variables. Where did you get this problem?

Comment: The problem is from my lecturer :) I used polar coordinates to compute it but our lecturer also wants us to learn how to prove our answers rigorously.

Comment: The polar coordinates were useful to gain an intuition as to what the limit actually evaluates to and what I would need to set out to prove, but weren't 'technically' correct.

Comment: @RubyPa that makes sense. The lecturer feels the class is fixated on methods that don't always work. Here is a problem where the $\delta, \epsilon$ part will be quite similar: $f(z)=\frac{a^2d^2 -2abcd + b^2c^2}{ \max(a^2 , b^2 , c^2 , d^2)}$

Comment: @RubyPa meanwhile, the standard problem where polar coordinates give the wrong answer is $\frac{x^2y}{x^4 + y^2}$

Comment: I am still confused as to what the $\delta$ should be taken to be, and per my update, what $|z| = |(a,b,c,d)|$ is.